# Как сделать редирект после подключения аккаунта Metamask?

Tags: редирект

```
    const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
    const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
    
    ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      getAccount();
    });
    
    async function getAccount() {
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      const account = accounts[0];
      showAccount.innerHTML = account;
}
```

У меня есть Connector к Metamask профилю,  коннект происходит через кнопку:

```
<button class="enableEthereumButton">Connect Metamask</button>
```

Как мне реализовать редирект, на определённую странницу только после подключения сайта к Metamask?

Answer (score 0):

Заменить строку

```
  showAccount.innerHTML = account;
```

на

```
  location.href = '/metamask-connected';
```